# convert a unix_timestamp to normal timestamp(with seconds) in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df.schema
```

op:

```
StructField(time,LongType,true)
```

Code:

```
df.registerTempTable("dfTbl")
dfNew= spark.sql("""
                 SELECT *, cast(time as Timestamp) as newTIMESTMP 
                 FROM dfTbl d
              """)
```

I am getting the output, but the values are weird.

ex:

```
50505-01-01
```

Any suggestions on what the mistakes could be?

Comment: What do you mean a normal timestamp? Do you want to format it as a string?

Comment: @Psidom nope, 'format: 2018-01-01 12:00:444.0'

Comment: `unix_timestamp` are integers in seconds. You can't add a fraction of second to it by conversion?

Comment: @Psidom I am not able to understand your comment.

Comment: If you look at your schema, `time` is LongType and its unit is `seconds`, and you want to convert it to `... 12:00:44.0` and there's a fraction of second in your format. I believe that is how utc timestamp stores time. See if `to_utc_timestamp` is what you needed.

Comment: @Psidom actually my unix_timestamp is in milliseconds

Comment: Are you sure? As I see from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), unix time stamp stores time as number of seconds.

Comment: @Psidom. I am sure. Epoch is in milliseconds.

Comment: I tried your code it works as expected. Can you post sample data that you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question, OP has the time field in epoch. So, it should be converted to seconds before executing the query.

```
df.registerTempTable("dfTbl")
dfNew= spark.sql("""
             SELECT *, cast(time/1000 as Timestamp) as newTIMESTMP 
             FROM dfTbl d
          """)
```

Answer (score 0):

pass your unixtimestamp to the below function

```
def unixtodate(utime):
  import datetime
  current=datetime.datetime(1970,01,01,00,00,00)+datetime.timedelta(seconds=utime)
  return current
```